# Ubuntu game server keeps turning it self off

Tags: server, games, minecraft, offline

I am running a game server from my home for my friends and I to play on. My server does stay up 24/7 because it is now a public server. My server runs for a few hours or days, and then randomly no matter what I do I can't wake the screen to access command line and the server is offline. Thanks any help is appreciated.

Comment: So you mean it has hung, not turned ( the power ) off?

Comment: I am unsure but I'll go with yes. The active power light is on but ssh in doesn't work and can't wake it without a hard restart. If that is what hung is then yes.

Comment: Login to the server (when it's working again), execute `journalctl -b -1 --catalog --pager-end` to see the last screenful of error messages before the last reboot.

Comment: I did that but it said "Specifying boot ID has no effect, no persistent journal was found"